# Xlwings safe Excel range as Python list

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I need to import an Excel range as a list in Python. I came up with the following basic code.

```
import xlwings as xw

r2 = xw.sheets('Tabelle1').range('A1').value # last row of range

r2 = int(r2)

r2 = str(r2)

r1 = 'B3:B' 

r3 = r1 + r2
InputData = [xw.sheets('Tabelle1').range(r3).value]
```

This code works perfectly fine when I start the code within my Spyder Environment. I will see the variable `InputData` as List in the variable explorer. However when I start the script from Excel/VBA using the Xlwings tool, the variable `InputData` will not be shown in the variable explorer.

Any ideas how I could modify this so the `InputData` variable will always be shown as a list, no matter how I start the script?

Comment: Only variables created by scripts that are run directly in Spyder will show up in the Spyder variable explorer. If a script is run in any other environment (like you're doing here) then it doesn't communicate with the Spyder application.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Is there any way around this problem? I thought about using excel to start a Python script, which calls the actual Python script. However this doesn't work neither.
 For user friendliness it would be great if only excel had to be started.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of your script? What has to be done with the values in `InputData`?

Comment: The big picture here is we would like to create a code, which downloads values from our database  automatically into excel. There the user can then manipulate the data. The variable  `InputData` is needed for the SQL query to download the data.

Comment: So if I understand correctly then you want all user controls, data input and data output to be in excel. If that's the case, then I still don't really understand why you want to involve the Spyder application. What purpose does the Spyder application serve in your scenario?

Comment: Spyder is only needed to access the database and manipulate the data accessed. Theoretically we could also do that in VBA however, the amounts of data processed may be large (while the final output is rather small) and Spyder seems to be more stable in processing larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the core of any Python installation is the interpreter. If you're working on a Windows machine, then the interpreter is an executable called `python.exe`. It is the piece of software that actually runs your Python code.

You can feed code to the interpreter in many different ways. One way is by means of the Spyder application. The Spyder application is in effect a human-friendly interface built on top of the interpreter. The Spyder application relays your Python commands to the interpreter, lets the interpreter run it, and then collects any outputs generated by the interpreter (e.g. calculated variable values which you can then view in Spyder's variable explorer).

But the Spyder application is only one of many possible ways to use the Python interpreter. You can also (and from what I understand this is what you're looking for) use an Excel application to feed Python code to the interpreter and handle all the outputs. In this case Excel is the interface on top of the Python interpreter instead of Spyder (i.e. Spyder is not needed at all).

This approach of using Excel (with VBA scripting) to do all control and communication with the Python interpreter is nicely demonstrated in these [example files](https://www.xlwings.org/examples) on the `xlwings` website. It even includes an example with database operations (using a SQLite database) I would suggest to download them and play around with them. Then go the `xlwings` documentation [here](https://www.xlwings.org?wvideo=zyxj327hse) and [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#macros-call-python-from-excel) to get a detailed understanding of what is happening in these examples.